# how does the tomcat ajp redirectport work if no connector is setup for the redirect to port

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat7

I've a tomcat server that is fronted by an apache server, both running on the same machine.  In the apache httpd.conf, I see this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /MACS ajp://10.50.3.23:38009/MACS retry=0 timeout=20000
```

In Tomcat server.xml, I see this:

```
<Connector port="38080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="16384"
           redirectPort="38443" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="38009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="38443" />
```

I see no connector setup for port 38443 in server.xml.  So, when I access the apacheserver/MACS link, how does the tomcat ajp connector knows to forward it to 38080?  (Note: The site work and the MACS application is running in the tomcat server.  So, I'm assuming that somehow the traffic got forwarded to 38080.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer it completely, but here are a few snippets of info that I gathered so far:

The AJP port is a separate connector. It doesn't redirect to the http port (38080 in your case), but just handles the request itself.  Unless you also intend to point your browser directly to tomcat (thus bypassing apache) you could (or even should) just comment out the plain http connector.

The redirectport specified may just be some syntactic boilerplate, to specify some kind of redirection that just won't ever happen, unless you add some specific configuration somewhere else in tomcat.